# plural form or singular form after a subject clause

Tags: grammatical-number

Which of the following is correct?

> What matters are people.
>
> What matters is people.
>
> What matter are people.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

SEE:  http://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/SubjectVerb.html  "When a Linking Verb is Used."

What matters is people; but people are what matters.